# Plex Media Server in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, plex

I'm using [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/) at PiMyLifeUp to set up a Plex Media Server on my Raspberry Pi. But, whenever I go to the address, it says the following:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<MediaContainer size="19" allowCameraUpload="0" allowChannelAccess="1" allowSharing="1" allowSync="0" backgroundProcessing="1" companionProxy="1" diagnostics="logs,databases" eventStream="1" friendlyName="raspberrypi" hubSearch="1" machineIdentifier="c25570232b830ec998f25efcd66125481fe4b42f" multiuser="1" myPlex="1" myPlexMappingState="mapped" myPlexSigninState="none" myPlexSubscription="0" photoAutoTag="1" platform="Linux" platformVersion="4.4.11-v7+ (#888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016)" pluginHost="1" readOnlyLibraries="0" requestParametersInCookie="1" streamingBrainVersion="1" sync="1" transcoderActiveVideoSessions="0" transcoderAudio="1" transcoderLyrics="1" transcoderPhoto="1" transcoderSubtitles="1" transcoderVideo="1" transcoderVideoBitrates="64,96,208,320,720,1500,2000,3000,4000,8000,10000,12000,20000" transcoderVideoQualities="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" transcoderVideoResolutions="128,128,160,240,320,480,768,720,720,1080,1080,1080,1080" updatedAt="1482450881" updater="1" version="1.3.3.3148-b38628e" voiceSearch="1">
<Directory count="1" key="activities" title="activities"/>
<Directory count="1" key="butler" title="butler"/>
<Directory count="1" key="channels" title="channels"/>
<Directory count="1" key="clients" title="clients"/>
<Directory count="1" key="diagnostics" title="diagnostics"/>
<Directory count="1" key="hubs" title="hubs"/>
<Directory count="1" key="library" title="library"/>
<Directory count="1" key="neighborhood" title="neighborhood"/>
<Directory count="1" key="playQueues" title="playQueues"/>
<Directory count="1" key="player" title="player"/>
<Directory count="1" key="playlists" title="playlists"/>
<Directory count="1" key="resources" title="resources"/>
<Directory count="1" key="search" title="search"/>
<Directory count="1" key="server" title="server"/>
<Directory count="1" key="servers" title="servers"/>
<Directory count="1" key="statistics" title="statistics"/>
<Directory count="1" key="system" title="system"/>
<Directory count="1" key="transcode" title="transcode"/>
<Directory count="1" key="updater" title="updater"/>
</MediaContainer>

Does anyone know what it means or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

@Sharan

I had the same problem,  found the answer in another forum. Try add "/manage" to the end of the url. A Plex setup wizard should run.

`http://ipaddress:32400/manage`

N.B remember to replace `ipaddress` with your IP. It apparently works with the hostname as well, but I would stick to using the address.

https://forums.lime-technology.com/topic/30196-when-accessing-plex-server-it-shows-quotthis-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any/

Comment: You only need to run the url with the "manage" end piece once, its for setting up the plex server.   After that you can access it via `http://ipaddress:32400/` normally

Comment: Since the time I've asked that question, I've realized that http://ipaddress:32400/web also works, but thx for helping.